# Having trouble with this java loop

Tags: java

My goal for this piece of code is to prompt the user to enter any number of boxes and then the program will draw the amount of boxes they enter, but have each one in a different position and different color. I'm not sure if i'm doing the loop right, and I can't figure out how to take the color I randomly generated in the paint method and use it in the drawBlock method.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Homework4 extends JPanel
{
    public int numBlocks;
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame ourFrame = new JFrame();
        ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ourFrame.setSize(500,500);
        ourFrame.setBackground( Color.white );

        Homework4 ourHomework4 = new Homework4();

        String numBlocksString=
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "How many blocks would you like?" );
        Integer.parseInt( numBlocksString );

        ourFrame.add( ourHomework4 );
        ourFrame.setVisible(true);   
    }

    public void paint( Graphics canvas )
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        Color blockColor = new Color( rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255) );
        if( numBlocks > 0)
        {
            {
                for( int i = 0; i < numBlocks; i++)
                {
                    this.drawBlock( canvas, rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500), blockColor ); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawBlock(Graphics g, int x, int y, Color blockColor )
    {
        g.setColor( blockColor );
        g.fillRect( x, y, 150, 150);
        //g.setColor( Color.white );
        g.fillRect( x+20, y+20, 110, 110);

    }

}
```

Comment: Well even without you telling us we know it doesn't compile because you have not specified a type for the blockColor parameter to `drawBlock`

Comment: I can't get to understand your question, could you please point out what is it about it you want and can't achieve? Also, there are a couple problems on your code: 1. The drawBlock method misses the blockColor parameter type. 2. You are redeclaring the numblocks variable in the main method, you should remove the int type

Comment: how do i use the color i created called "blockColor" with random numbers, in the method below that draws the block. @SEAang

Comment: You already got it, the problem is you set the graphics Color to the one generated, but two lines below, you set it back to White. Try removing that Color.white line and check if it works. Remember to fix both errors I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: @SEAang How do I add the blockColor parameter type to the drawBlock method? 
something like
public void drawBlack( Graphics g, int x, int y, blockColor)

Comment: @SEAang also would it make more sense to use a while loop instead?

Comment: @user7538286 the method signature would have to be like follows: public void drawBlock(Graphics g, int x, int y, Color blockColor)
About the while vs for discussion, it's more about personal preferences; in this case I would use the "for loop" as you have it. Also, the "if statement" around the for, is not necessary.

Comment: @SEAang yeah i realized there was an extra if statement. At this point my code compiles, but it doesn't actually draw anything. Do you see what the problem could be?

Comment: Please update the code you have, or repost it so the community can help

Comment: @SEAang i updated it in the original post

Comment: @user7538286 Basically the numBlocks variable is never being assigned, so its value is always 0.

On the main method change this line: 
`numBlocks = Integer.parseInt( numBlocksString );`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in the source code you've posted in the question.

1. You will have to assign the numBlocks variable in the main method, where you are asking the user for the amount of blocks.
2. That variable numBlocks must be static, so you could actually assign it in the static main method.
3. You are trying to paint every single block with the same random color, since it's outside the "for-loop", so the Color initialization should be inside the loop so each block have different colors.
4. The "if-statement" is not itself wrong or a problem, but it's not doing anything at all, so I removed it.
5. I did some code format on the source code you posted, so it's a little bit more clear what it does.

Here is the complete-updated code you're looking for:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Homework4 extends JPanel {
    public static int numBlocks;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame ourFrame = new JFrame();
        ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ourFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        ourFrame.setBackground(Color.white);

        Homework4 ourHomework4 = new Homework4();

        String numBlocksString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many blocks would you like?");
        numBlocks = Integer.parseInt(numBlocksString);

        ourFrame.add(ourHomework4);
        ourFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics canvas) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numBlocks; i++) {
            Color blockColor = new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
            this.drawBlock(canvas, rand.nextInt(500), rand.nextInt(500), blockColor);
        }
    }

    public void drawBlock(Graphics g, int x, int y, Color blockColor) {

        g.setColor(blockColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 150, 150);
        g.fillRect(x + 20, y + 20, 110, 110);

    }

}
```

The output on any random execution (with a number of blocks: 7) could looks like:

[image: Homework4 Execution with 7 blocks]

Hope this answer helps and it could clear your doubts and you understand everything.